# CheckStyle warning unable to recognize exceptions like ServletException, HibernateException

Tags: java, code-formatting, checkstyle

I'm working on cleaning up my code by adding checkstyle warning configurations for my project. In this process, I added a module name RedundantThrows in sun_checks.xml. I see the following warnings,

**Unable to get class information for ServletException.**

**Unable to get class information for HibernateException.**

So, it seems that CheckStyle is unable to recognize classes HibernateException, ServletException..

Is there any way that I can make CheckStyle to have access to the jars which contains these classes?

Thanks in advance!